# javadoc and package private interface?

Tags: java, javadoc, package-private

This maybe the same issue with [How can I prevent a package-private interface appearing in Javadoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1537220/330457).
But I thing the situation is a little bit different.

```
interface Child<P> { // package-private!!! internal-use only!!!
    P getParent();
    void setParent(P parent);
}

public class John implements Child<Jane> {
}
```

When I generate the javadoc, I see following definitions on John's page.

```
getParent
    public P getParent()
setParent
    public void setParent(P parent)
```

Is this normal? Is there any way to hide those methods defined in the package-private interface?

Comment: The implementation of those methods is still `public`. They are regularly accessible.

Answer (score 3):

from the [JavaTutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html):

> The interface body can contain abstract methods, default methods, and
>   static methods. An abstract method within an interface is followed by
>   a semicolon, but no braces (an abstract method does not contain an
>   implementation). Default methods are defined with the default
>   modifier, and static methods with the static keyword. All abstract,
>   default, and static methods in an interface **are implicitly public**, so
>   you can omit the public modifier.

Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640222/distinguishing-internal-external-methods-for-javadoc) to see if the provided approach helps you to hide the desired methods of the javadoc.